# How to generate a class with a custom interface via kotlinpoet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I want to generate a kotlin class definition, this class implements an customized interface, the target class definition as below:

```
data class TemplateState(val data: String) : ContractState {
}
```

I used below poet code to generate it except the interface part, anyone can help?

```
val file = FileSpec.builder("com.template", "StatesAndContracts")
        .addType(TypeSpec.classBuilder("TemplateState")
                .addModifiers(KModifier.DATA)
                .primaryConstructor(FunSpec.constructorBuilder()
                .addParameter("data", String::class)
                .build())
                .addProperty(PropertySpec.builder("data", String::class)
                .initializer("data")
                .build())
                .build())
        .build()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `addSuperInterface` method, which you can chain to the `TypeSpec` builder:

```
TypeSpec.classBuilder("TemplateState")
        .addSuperinterface(ClassName("", "ContractState"))
        ...
```

If you have the package name for the `ContractState` class, you can add it as the first parameter of the `ClassName` constructor. Or if you can reference the `ContractState` type directly, you can create the `TypeName` instance with a `ParameterizedTypeName.get(...)` call.